# Should I use an SQL database for user administration on a Neo4j based project?

Tags: nosql, neo4j

I am planning a large project that is going to use Neo4j as main storage to model the data, but I was wondering if I should additionally use something like MySQL as a parallel structure to back the user administration subsystem. It would have the advantage that I could use something with which I have much more experience (18 Years) to do the very tedious job of login and account administration. The disadvantage would be the overhead of keeping two databases in sync, since I do plan to have the users also represented as nodes in Neo4j with a small subset of the user information. I know that it depends a lot on the details of the project, but if anybody has experience in the field with a similar set up it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than building replication, stick to your chosen database & build administration tools and UI. Replication is complex & difficult, admin tools hopefully less so.

If you can't get the data out at least in CSV for reporting, maybe reconsider choice of DB.

Comment: I have been giving this question a lot of thought. Replicating IDs is not that much of a problem, we have been doing it for ages id RDBMs, but I am giving you the answer because at the end, having all data on a single paradigm has indeed a lot of benefits.

Comment: Yes, you always need admin tools in the end. Relying on a SQL tool/ database console tool is not safe or scalable.. too easy for people to get an UPDATE or DELETE statement wrong.